# Jframe not repainting issue

Tags: java, swing, drawing, 2d

I have a program which is simple in function. On start, it creates a random circle which it places in the window/frame. When that circle is clicked, it should dissappear, and spawn a new circle elsewhere. the issue is, my program does this, but you see all the past circles unless you minimize/reopen the window. I cannot get it to repaint without my help... and I do NOT know why. Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Core extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
public static ArrayList<Ellipse2D> list = new ArrayList<Ellipse2D>();
Random r = new Random();


public Ellipse2D  spawn(){

    int x = r.nextInt(this.getWidth());
    int y = r.nextInt(this.getHeight());

    while(x<75||x>this.getWidth()-150){
        x = r.nextInt(this.getWidth());
    }
    while(y<75||y>this.getHeight()-150){
        y = r.nextInt(this.getHeight());
    }
    System.out.println("MAKING SHAPE at :" + x + " AND " + y);
    return new  Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 75, 75);
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    // Save the coordinates of the click lke this.
    if(list.get(0).contains(me.getPoint())){
        System.out.println("CLICKED SHAPE!");
        list.clear();

        list.add(spawn());


    }
    revalidate();
  repaint();
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    if(list.size()==0){
        System.out.println("oops");

    }
    if(!list.isEmpty()){

    System.out.println("DRAW");
int x =(int) list.get(0).getX();
int y =(int) list.get(0).getY();
int width = (int) list.get(0).getWidth();
int height = (int) list.get(0).getHeight();

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawOval(x,y, width, height);
    }


}
public Core(){

setSize(500, 500);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.addMouseListener(this);
list.add(spawn());
setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String args[]) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Core();


        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Don't draw on the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Comment: That is not helpful at all. you could at least show me what you mean in my code or post what should change. That did not help whatsoever.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you read *programs that ignore this rule may function correctly most of the time, but are subject to unpredictable errors that are difficult to reproduce*? In `paint`, you're drawing on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: No. I do not normally use strictly java to code or draw.. usually i have a graphics library. So if i'm not supposed to draw on paint, what method do I use?

Answer (score 4):

Your code works perfectly fine for me, however...

- Don't override `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame`, `JFrame` contains a `JRootPane`, which contains a `contentPane` and may also have a visible `glassPane`, all of which can overpaint what is painted within the `paint` method.  As a general rule, you shouldn't extend from `JFrame` (or other top level containers), you are locking yourself into a single use case, reducing the re-usability of your component and you're not actually any new functionality to the class.  Instead, use a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method
- Call `super.paint` before doing any custom painting.  If, however, you use a `JPanel`, call `super.paintComponent`.  Painting is performed by a series of methods which are chained together to generate the final output.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details
- Consider using something like `x = r.nextInt(this.getWidth() - 150) + 75;` and `y = r.nextInt(this.getWidth() - 150) + 75;` instead of your while loops, I think you might find them safer to use

For example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Core {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Core();
            }
        });
    }

    public Core() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new CorePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class CorePane extends JPanel {

        private ArrayList<Ellipse2D> list = new ArrayList<Ellipse2D>();
        private Random r = new Random();

        public Ellipse2D spawn() {

            int x = r.nextInt(this.getWidth());
            int y = r.nextInt(this.getHeight());

            x = r.nextInt(this.getWidth() - 150) + 75;
            y = r.nextInt(this.getWidth() - 150) + 75;
            System.out.println("MAKING SHAPE at :" + x + " AND " + y);
            return new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 75, 75);
        }

        public CorePane() {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                    // Save the coordinates of the click lke this.
                    if (list.get(0).contains(me.getPoint())) {
                        list.clear();

                        list.add(spawn());

                    }
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidate() {
            super.invalidate();
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (list.isEmpty()) {
                        list.add(spawn());
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 500);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                for (Ellipse2D ellipse : list) {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
                    g2d.draw(ellipse);
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Or, based on what I believe you're trying to do, you could simply do something like...

```
public class CorePane extends JPanel {

    private Random r = new Random();
    private Ellipse2D ellipse;

    public Ellipse2D spawn() {

        int x = r.nextInt(this.getWidth());
        int y = r.nextInt(this.getHeight());

        x = r.nextInt(this.getWidth() - 150) + 75;
        y = r.nextInt(this.getWidth() - 150) + 75;
        System.out.println("MAKING SHAPE at :" + x + " AND " + y);
        return new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 75, 75);
    }

    public CorePane() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                if (ellipse != null && ellipse.contains(me.getPoint())) {
                    ellipse = spawn();
                }
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        super.invalidate();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                spawn();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        if (ellipse != null) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.red);
            g2d.draw(ellipse);
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. My only question is how do I use the JPanel? wouldn't I have to rewrite the whole class?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is it truly advisable to use `paintComponent` for anything other than overriding the natural painting of the JPanel (i.e. for custom loading bars, custom UI, etc.) ?

Comment: @InsidiarumCrassescit For custom UI's you would use a custom UI delegate.  For basic painting, it is recommended to override `paintComponent` - Child components can be painted without causing parent components to be repainted, which can result in some very weird results

Comment: @user2680805 You wouldn't need to rewrite the entire class, just move the functionality.

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's quite interesting! I've always thought it better to do so the other way around, in case the System decided to repaint at all the wrong times, and such. If you don't mind, could you provide me with a bit of reading material on the subject? Thanks for your insight!

Comment: @InsidiarumCrassescit There are rare use cases where you might override `paint`, but for the vast majority of the time, `paintComponent` is the better choice.  Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)